# Mlagents-learn train: "The Unity environment took too long to respond."

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, ml-agent

I am trying to write my own game using ml-agents for AI and I obviously want to train it, but when I try to I see only this:

> [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtMdJ.png)

I tried to run 3dBall example project and everything is running fine when I train it. I did everything according to basic guide in documentation of ml-agents and I don't know what am I doing wrong. I have ML-Agents assets imported into my project some simple code for Agent and empty Academy.

Any help would be appreciated :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/issues/2528

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same error, make sure you have added the decision requester component to the agent. Solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are many variables that could cause this. Verify the version of your python and mlagents are the same. Verify too that you have added you agent and academy into your scene. It's possible too that you forgot to add a continuous Behaviour to your agent.

I really suggest to read this documentation:  https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Learning-Environment-Create-New.md

it's very possible your project is already out of date, so please update you mlagents pip install and create a new project.